# google-bigquery UDF for jaro_winkle_distance

Tags: google-bigquery

I am the following UDF code that calculate jaro_winkle_distance
It seems to work when test it with json test data but when I try to call it in the google-bigquery UI, it keeps consistently gives me a score of zero.
even with self join e.g.

input:

```
[
 {a: "Liu",b:"Lau"},
 {a: "John",b:"Jone"}]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "scr": 80
  },
  {
    "scr": 87
  }
]
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  jwd(a STRING,
    b STRING)
  RETURNS INT64
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    // Assumes 'doInterestingStuff' is defined in one of the library files.
    //return doInterestingStuff(a, b);
    return jaro_winkler_distance(a,b);
""" OPTIONS ( library="gs://kayama808/javascript/jaro_winkler_google_UDF.js" );
SELECT
  x.name name1,
  jwd(x.name,
    x.name) scr
FROM
   babynames.usa_1910_2013_copy x
WHERE
  x.gender = 'F' and x.number >= 1000 and x.state = 'CA'
ORDER BY
  scr DESC;
```

http://storage.googleapis.com/bigquery-udf-test-tool/testtool.html

https://storage.cloud.google.com/kayama808/javascript/jaro_winkler_google_UDF.js?_ga=1.184402278.1320598031.1475534357

Comment: I try using float64 instead of int64 but it is still  not working https://bigquery.cloud.google.com:443/savedquery/470771908106:2efeb6b98f2549949bbd6c1c595ef7b7 https://storage.googleapis.com/kayama808/javascript/jaro_winkler_google_UDF2.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below. It works as expected with result as

```
name1   name2   scr  
Liu     Liu     100  
John    Jone     87  
Liu     Lau      80
```

Hopefully, you will be able to put it back to your external lib file :o)

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION jwd(a STRING, b STRING)
  RETURNS INT64
  LANGUAGE js AS """
/* JS implementation of the strcmp95 C function written by
Bill Winkler, George McLaughlin, Matt Jaro and Maureen Lynch,
released in 1994 (http://web.archive.org/web/20100227020019/http://www.census.gov/geo/msb/stand/strcmp.c).

a and b should be strings. Always performs case-insensitive comparisons
and always adjusts for long strings. */

var jaro_winkler_adjustments = {
  'A': 'E',
  'A': 'I',
  'A': 'O',
  'A': 'U',
  'B': 'V',
  'E': 'I',
  'E': 'O',
  'E': 'U',
  'I': 'O',
  'I': 'U',
  'O': 'U',
  'I': 'Y',
  'E': 'Y',
  'C': 'G',
  'E': 'F',
  'W': 'U',
  'W': 'V',
  'X': 'K',
  'S': 'Z',
  'X': 'S',
  'Q': 'C',
  'U': 'V',
  'M': 'N',
  'L': 'I',
  'Q': 'O',
  'P': 'R',
  'I': 'J',
  '2': 'Z',
  '5': 'S',
  '8': 'B',
  '1': 'I',
  '1': 'L',
  '0': 'O',
  '0': 'Q',
  'C': 'K',
  'G': 'J',
  'E': ' ',
  'Y': ' ', 
  'S': ' '
};

  if (!a || !b) { return 0.0; }

  a = a.trim().toUpperCase();
  b = b.trim().toUpperCase();
  var a_len = a.length;
  var b_len = b.length;
  var a_flag = []; var b_flag = [];
  var search_range = Math.floor(Math.max(a_len, b_len) / 2) - 1;
  var minv = Math.min(a_len, b_len);

  // Looking only within the search range, count and flag the matched pairs. 
  var Num_com = 0;
  var yl1 = b_len - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < a_len; i++) {
    var lowlim = (i >= search_range) ? i - search_range : 0;
    var hilim  = ((i + search_range) <= yl1) ? (i + search_range) : yl1;
    for (var j = lowlim; j <= hilim; j++) {
      if (b_flag[j] !== 1 && a[j] === b[i]) {
        a_flag[j] = 1;
        b_flag[i] = 1;
        Num_com++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Return if no characters in common
  if (Num_com === 0) { return 0.0; }

  // Count the number of transpositions
  var k = 0; var N_trans = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < a_len; i++) {
    if (a_flag[i] === 1) {
      var j;
      for (j = k; j < b_len; j++) {
        if (b_flag[j] === 1) {
          k = j + 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (a[i] !== b[j]) { N_trans++; }
    }
  }
  N_trans = Math.floor(N_trans / 2);

  // Adjust for similarities in nonmatched characters
  var N_simi = 0; var adjwt = jaro_winkler_adjustments;
  if (minv > Num_com) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a_len; i++) {
      if (!a_flag[i]) {
        for (var j = 0; j < b_len; j++) {
          if (!b_flag[j]) {
            if (adjwt[a[i]] === b[j]) {
              N_simi += 3;
              b_flag[j] = 2;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var Num_sim = (N_simi / 10.0) + Num_com;

  // Main weight computation
  var weight = Num_sim / a_len + Num_sim / b_len + (Num_com - N_trans) / Num_com;
  weight = weight / 3;

  // Continue to boost the weight if the strings are similar
  if (weight > 0.7) {
    // Adjust for having up to the first 4 characters in common
    var j = (minv >= 4) ? 4 : minv;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; (i < j) && a[i] === b[i]; i++) { }
    if (i) { weight += i * 0.1 * (1.0 - weight) };

    // Adjust for long strings.
    // After agreeing beginning chars, at least two more must agree
    // and the agreeing characters must be more than half of the
    // remaining characters.
    if (minv > 4 && Num_com > i + 1 && 2 * Num_com >= minv + i) {
      weight += (1 - weight) * ((Num_com - i - 1) / (a_len * b_len - i*2 + 2));
    }
  }

    return Math.round(weight*100);

""";

SELECT
  name1, name2,
  jwd(name1, name2) scr
FROM -- babynames.usa_1910_2013_copy x
  (
  select "Liu" as name1, "Lau" as name2 union all
  select "Liu" as name1, "Liu" as name2 union all
  select "John" as name1, "Jone" as name2 
  ) x
ORDER BY scr DESC
```

In addition: I've just double checked your jaro_winkler_google_UDF2.js file and clearly see that issue is in this file.
Fix this file using code in my answer

Or, just remove below lines in it

```
var a = r.a;
var b = r.b;
```

and uncomment

```
//jaro_winkler.distance = function(a, b) {

//return Math.round(weight*100)
```

and comment all with `emit` in it

```
jaro_winkler_distance=function(r, emit) {

emit(weight);
```

You should be ok then!

Comment: We use the inline JavaScript example you give and it works. However, we try to use the google storage and put the javascript there instead of having it inline. It looks like for doing that it asks for emit to work Error: ReferenceError: emit is not defined at gs://kayama808/javascript/jaro_winkler_google_UDF3.js line 154, columns 4-5

Comment: Is there an end to end example on google-bigquery that uses javascript UDF in storage. It shows the example in the doc but it does not include the JS code. And in the test-tool it uses emit in the javascript. And Why cant google just use JS UDF "AS-IS" ??

Comment: i believe, test tool is for legacy version of UDF  - which is table valued UDF - vs Scalar UDF in Standard

Comment: i will check/test with lib, but meantime - can you use inline version?

Comment: can you copy paste that line (154) so i will check what it is there  - most likely it is something that reference emit  - but as I pointed in my answer  - there should not be referencing of emit at all!

Comment: :o( let me know if you need more help with this

Comment: Its working now. https://storage.googleapis.com/kayama808/javascript/jaro_winkler_google_UDF6.js https://bigquery.cloud.google.com:443/savedquery/470771908106:61dd81462d6f4c01b9c1d0704b2ca1ab  Thanks for all the help =)

Comment: great. if not yet - consider also voting up the answer :o)

Comment: also my jsbin for testing the UDF JS code. https://jsbin.com/wawamex/6/edit?html,js,output It looks like emit is not needed as you say so why in the test-tool it put emit there.

Comment: because test-tool is for Legacy SQL UDF. Thos are Table scope UDF  - they are also cool in some use cases. You can check Legacy SQL UDF - [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions). Google has introduced this tool long ago - because without it  - testing of Legacy UDF was quite a problem. With Standard SQL  - testing Scalar UDF does not require this tool at all  -you can test it in any js client as any other regular js function